# Unable to Deserialize - Jackson LocalDate/Time - JUnit

Tags: java, jackson, junit5, jackson-databind

I need to deserialize the Json to Java Objects in Junit. I have Json file like

```
{
   "studentId":57,
   "JoinedDate":"31-12-2019",
   "DOB":"08-06-1998"  

}
```

I have class for the same to map

```
public class Student{

    private long studentId ;

    private LocalDate JoinedDate;

    private LocalDate DOB ;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public LocalDate getJoinedDate() {
        return JoinedDate;
    }

    public void setJoinedDate(LocalDate joinedDate) {
        JoinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(LocalDate dOB) {
        DOB = dOB;
    }
```

I need to write centralized builder for Unit testing project similar like this

```
builder.deserializers(new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
```

Main Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Main{
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

Unit testing Project looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class StudentTest{

private ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper;
@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {

    jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    studentJson = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream(CommonTestConstants.StudentPath+ "/Student.json"));


}
```

I'm getting a error while mapping the objects -
**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "31-12-2019": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate:**

Another Error - Sometimes.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '31-12-2019'
>   could not be parsed at index 0

I assume LocalDate format mismatch is the issue. Any suggestion to make it centralized way instead of specifying the format above the fields. Any one please advise?

Reference - [Spring Boot JacksonTester custom serializer not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210284/spring-boot-jacksontester-custom-serializer-not-registered)

Comment: Can you try something like this? ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));

Comment: I tried your suggestion - It's not working @Govind

Comment: Getting Error: Multiple Failures (2 failures)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('31-12-2019')

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the date format by default jackson allows format of yyyy-MM-dd

```
public class Student{

    private long studentId ;

@JsonProperty("JoinedDate") @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")

    private LocalDate JoinedDate;

@JsonProperty("DOB") @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate DOB ;

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public LocalDate getJoinedDate() {
        return JoinedDate;
    }

    public void setJoinedDate(LocalDate joinedDate) {
        this.JoinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getDOB() {
        return DOB;
    }

    public void setDOB(LocalDate dOB) {
        this.DOB = dOB;
    }
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks @Ashish - I tried your suggestion. I'm getting a error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('31-12-2019')

Comment: @Debugger check JSON date format and POJO date format. it seems like you are validating with different date format.

Answer (score 1):

Springboot `1.4.x` or above has this interface `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` which allows you to initialize `objectMapper`.

What we need to do, is override `customize` method and register `deserializers` and
`serializers`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
     // pattern could be anything whatever is required
     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/dd/MM");

     LocalDateSerializer localDateDeserializer = new LocalDateSerializer(formatter);

     jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
       .failOnEmptyBeans(false)
       .deserializersByType(new HashMap<Class<?>, JsonDeserializer<?>>(){{
         put(LocalTime.class, localTimeSerializer);
       }});
    }
}
```

We can also add `seriliazers` similar way.

```
jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
   .failOnEmptyBeans(false)
   .serializersByType(new HashMap<Class<?>, JsonSerializer<?>>(){{
         put(LocalTime.class, localTimeSerializer);
   }});
```

you can check more details here. [Spring Jackson builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html)

Comment: Thanks - I tried your suggestion -I'm getting a error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '31-12-2019' could not be parsed at index 0 (through reference chain: com.bre.fact.model.CautionFact["matchDate"])- Can you pls advise @lucid

Comment: I'm using @SpringBootTest, because for Unit testing

Comment: @Debugger can you add little bit of `Main.class` just class level annotation ?